# How do I populate a list of BLE iPads and iPhones using core bluetooth

Tags: ios7, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to create a simple browser using core bluetooth that discovers iPhones and iPads in the vicinity and displays them in a table view. Thus far, i'm implementing central Manager and receiving a notification. The information seems a little cryptic

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
    NSLog(@"Did discover peripheral. peripheral: %@ rssi: %@, UUID: %@ advertisementData: %@ ", peripheral, RSSI, peripheral.UUID, advertisementData);
}
```

The information seems a little cryptic, for and for some reason not all of the devices have a "name" parameter.

2014-09-22 13:11:13.142 WhoDat[3333:60b] Did discover peripheral. peripheral:

```
0x1780b4f40 identifier = 9373F3AD-726D-2EC9-AB2C-BBAB9B2ED319, Name = "(null)", state = disconnected> rssi: -63, UUID: <CFUUID 0x178036ee0> 9373F3AD-726D-2EC9-AB2C-BBAB9B2ED319 advertisementData: {
    kCBAdvDataChannel = 37;
    kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
}
```

while others do

```
2014-09-22 13:13:26.224 WhoDat[3333:60b] Did discover peripheral. peripheral: <CBPeripheral: 0x1700b4b80 identifier = 74E42396-CB35-3FB7-A855-F2BB78AC2C78, Name = "Zip", state = disconnected> rssi: -95, UUID: <CFUUID 0x17002da60> 74E42396-CB35-3FB7-A855-F2BB78AC2C78 advertisementData: {
    kCBAdvDataChannel = 39;
    kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
    kCBAdvDataServiceData =     {
        "Device Information" = <0204>;
    };
    kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =     (
        "ADAB67D3-6E7D-4601-BDA2-BFFAA68956BA"
    );
}
```

but I seem to have no way of differentiating what is what. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can filter if you want checking if `name` is `null` or not. The thing, is that not all device have the same info in the advertisement data (for example, no `kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs`). As another info, the iPhone will get by "piece" all the info, that's why sometimes name is `null` for example.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason you are not receiving a name is that the device is not advertising one inside of it's advertising package.

To make matters stranger, CoreBluetooth does some caching which will create strange inconsistencies when interacting with a device.

A chief example being a device that does not advertise it's name will show it's cached name if you connect to said device.

My suggestion would be to represent it with a string of "No Name" until you receive one via connecting to said device.